# Getting null pointer exception when inflate a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to inflate a Gallery and Text, so I creates a gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout00"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" />
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gallery" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to show multiple gallery , so i add galleries dynamically.
When I inflate it , I am getting null pointer exception.

```
    public class PayPerViewActivity extends Activity  implements OnItemClickListener{
GridView gridview  = null;
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = null;
private Gallery gallery[] ;
DataProvider dataProvider ;
LazyAdapter adapter[];
String[] values = null;
View view[];
static class ViewHolder extends LinearLayout{
    public ViewHolder(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public Gallery g;
    public TextView text;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.galleris);

    final LayoutInflater  inflater =     (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int count = 1;
    gallery = new Gallery[Config.NO_OF_GALLERY];
    adapter = new LazyAdapter[Config.NO_OF_GALLERY];
    LinearLayout innerLayout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout02);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < Config.NO_OF_GALLERY ; i++){
        values = new String[Config.IMAGES_PER_GALLERY]; 
        for(int j = 0 ; j<Config.IMAGES_PER_GALLERY ;j++){
            values[j]= Config.MOVIE_URL+count+Config.IMAGE_EXT;
            count++;
        }
        ViewHolder vi = new ViewHolder(this);
        view[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery, null);// Null pointer exception on this line

        gallery[i] = (Gallery) view[i].findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        adapter[i] = new LazyAdapter(this,dataProvider.getInstance().getGallery().get(""+i).getData());
        gallery[i].setAdapter(adapter[i]);
        gallery[i].setOnItemClickListener(this);

        vi.g = gallery[i];
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText("kid");
        vi.text = textView;
        view[i].setTag(vi);
        innerLayout.addView(view[i]);
                }

}   @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    String tag =  (String) v.getTag();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailedViewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("url", tag);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

I am not able to debug why it giving null pointer exception.Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `view` variable is null. You need to initialize it before setting `view[i]` to something, for example

```
view = new View[Config.NO_OF_GALLERY];
```

as you do it for `gallery` and `adapter` arrays.

Or use collections for this (particularly `List`).